# Android Bluetooth Audio Routing/Audio manage Tasker

Tags: javascript, android, audio, bluetooth, tasker

I have two audio devices paired. I can use Samsung Quick Connect to select which speaker to play to. It doesn't unpair or repair. It does it instantly. How can I use tasker to do this? Or implement a Java Function in tasker to do this? AudioManager class?